# eval-when-compile: Is my understanding correct?

Tags: compilation, eval

I want to build a ring of symbols in my init.el for the purpose of rotating themes. I could do it like this:

```
(let* ((themes '(doom-one zenburn leuven))
       (ring (make-ring (length themes))))
  (mapc (lambda (x) (ring-insert ring x))
        themes)
  (setq my-theme-ring ring))
```

which results in the following data-structure

```
(0 3 . [doom-one zenburn leuven])
```

Or, I could build it more directly:

```
(let* ((vector [doom-one zenburn leuven])
       (ring `(0 ,(length vector) . ,vector)))
  (setq my-theme-ring ring)
```

The first approach goes through the ring.el public API and makes no assumptions about its implementation.

The second approach does less work, but could break if ring.el changes its implementation.

I *think* I can use *eval-when-compile* to get the best of both worlds:

```
(setq my-theme-ring
      (eval-when-compile
        (let* ((themes '(doom-one zenburn leuven))
               (ring (make-ring (length themes))))
          (mapc (lambda (x) (ring-insert ring x))
                themes)
          ring)))
```

Or maybe even:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (let* ((themes '(doom-one zenburn leuven))
         (ring (make-ring (length themes))))
    (mapc (lambda (x) (ring-insert ring x))
          themes)
    (setq my-theme-ring ring)))
```

When I compile my init file, it will iterate over the themes and add them one-by-one to the ring. When I start Emacs and load my already compiled init file, however, it will just read the already populated ring that resulted during compilation.

Is that right? And if so, can I nest the *setq* call within the *eval-when-compile* body too, as I've done in the last code snippet, or can I only use the compiled result for the value it returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the `setq` into the `eval-when-compile` means that the variable will be assigned during byte-compilation but not when you load `init.elc`, so it's probably not what you want.

BTW, I'd recommend `(dolist (x '(doom-one zenburn leuven)) (ring-insert ring x))` over using `mapc`, tho it's largely a question of taste.

Comment: I suspected as much about putting the `setq` in the body of `eval-when-compile` -- good to know, thanks!